# PC reboots automatically in the begining

Tags: windows-7, reboot

I have a AMD Phenom II 3GHz. 2 GB RAM system running on Windows 7. Off late my PC does not start properly I have to start it at least 7-8 times before it starts. It starts and then shuts down. Every time the time for which the system is up increases. After 7-8 attempts it starts an works fine. I have to give it a min between restarts (USB mouse light goes off). If I try restarting before this time the PC does not start. I am suspecting humidity playing some factor as this issue has started creeping up ever since the rains have started.

Comment: Have you tried using a different power supply? This could be the cultrate and this would either confirm it, or eliminate it as a suspect of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if the CPU's fan is working properly. Maybe when the PC starts it is spinning slow and the CPU is heating up, so it reboots the system

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the PSU is on it's way out, I've had a few where it was almost like they had to warm up before they would work, easiest way to test, pop another power supply in the machine, see if it starts normally, if it doesn't, here's a checklist of what to do on similar question I just answered.

[Computer loop restarts on Windows loading](https://superuser.com/questions/611689/computer-loop-restarts-on-windows-loading/611786#611786)