# Computer loop restarts on Windows loading

Tags: windows

**My computer restarts, just after or during Windows loading** (4 squares getting together), or after some time on the desktop IF I'm idle.

In order to start the computer I either have to swap my RAM (24Go) in differents DIMM slots, for example (I have 4 slots) : 1-2-4 or 2-3-4 or 1-3-4, not the same position each boot or it restarts in a loop...

I can also change the ram timing from 1.5 to 1.6V and it starts, at the next reboot I have to change it again to 1.5 or it won't boot...

And If after all, I succeed to boot, **I have to use the computer for about 10 minutes, and it's ok**, if I don't, it restarts by itself after some minutes.

**If I stay on the BIOS**, It's all OK, I can stay for a whole year without restarting.

- I have check my RAM on Memtest (4*8G SDRAM DDR3) : OK
- I have check without graphic card : Still the same.
- I tried to reset the bios stack by getting it off and on : Still the same.
- I tried to reset my BIOS, and many settings about the RAM in the menu : Still the same.
- CPU temps are just fine (around 35°C)

I was thinking ofc about the motherboard but I want to be sure.

Motherboard : MSI zh77a-g43
RAM : 4*8G Dual Mode or not (depends on the number I put ofc.)
PSU : 600W (enough to run all the config)
CPU : i7 3770 non K

Comment: Try with usb live linux. You will see if the system restart.

Comment: Oh, I forgot, restarting even in a live CD of an external OS. But in the loading of the live CD, like the drivers are the cause of the problem you know, that's weird.

Comment: @RobinsonG. - You are last comment makes no sense please clarify it.

Comment: Sorry about this. I meant, when I boot from a live CD, the computer is also rebooting, it often happens when the live CD is loading drivers. 
And, when I boot on Windows, the reboot happens at the end of the loading screen, before the login screen. So maybe the loading of some drivers are the cause of the failure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove any peripherals, upgraded hardware, etc and leave only what came with the tower and attempt to get past post with just the hard drive and the onboard graphics.

If you can get windows to boot and it runs without crashing then we know the problem exists within one or more of the peripherals, if the same issue persists, disconnect the hard drive as well and try starting a linux distro via USB, if problem persists, try using a different processor/RAM in the tower as to rule out if that is the problem or not.

If the problem persists, then the RAM/processor were not at fault, next will be testing the power supply, try booting up bare basics with a different PSU, if the problem persists, rule that out, all that's left is the motherboard.

Sorry if this is a bit scrambled, I'm currently working on a system myself that doesn't seem to want to even get to POST, from what you've said though, I've seen a similar problem once, sounds like the PSU is on it's way out, so if you like you could start with that first.

Comment: I have to admit, I'm lazy and I didn't start this way. I will test each component of my computer individually, and try to diagnose the problem. Thanks for the answer.

PS : Do you think a PSU can cause BSODs ?

Comment: Yes, it happened to me almost a year ago, I didn't think it at first and cloned my hard drive to look for issues, finally went over every component and found it was the PSU.

Comment: Also, make sure to check over the capacitors on the board and in the PSU, I checked over the PSU after to find a capacitor had begun to leak, check for bloating/bending or leaks. If this fixes it or at least helps you find what the problem is, feel free to upvote or mark as answer, I'm noting that on all my answers now since I have 40 some now that I fixed the problem, to get no rep from.

Comment: Thank you user88311, I will do some test on my computer this week, hope I will diagnose this problem.

Comment: No problem, and a side note I forgot to mention, sometimes due to either age, where solder oxidizes after a while, or due to extreme heat, solder on components such as onboard graphics processors can crack, and cause the system not to post, simply using a method known as a reflow can fix the issue for anywheres from weeks, to a year. What a reflow is taking a heat gun, which is a over powered hair drier, and laying the system on it's side on a level surface, you can take the board out if you wish or leave it in, just remove any other hardware first, and blowing heat onto the.

Comment: GPU heat spreaders in order to heat the solder to liquid point, so it reconnects, alternatively, if you don't have a heat gun believe it or not, a powerful hair drier will work to, but is not likely to complete liquefy the solder, just expand it enough so you can boot and keep running till it's shut down, figured I'd tack that on there, I plan to make a full POST debug how and repair guide on here eventually.

Comment: Hi everyone, and thanks for the details user88311 ;)

Yesterday, I built my config with a new motherboard/chassis/graphic card/watercooling system, and unfortunately still have the same problem. 
The RAM has been tested on Memtest, each one, no errors.

So, I'm asking now, about my SDD. Can the MBR be defaulting ?
I mean, sometimes even if I load the Windows install disk, it's rebooting, so I don't really think so...

I just hope this is not the CPU...

Thank you guys.