# Debugging a laptop that won't turn on

Tags: laptop, motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure, diagnostic

When laptop won't turn on, how do I figure out which of these issues might it be?

1. Power Button
2. The AC plug
3. The Motherboard

Are there some tools or ways to debug and narrow down the cause. And how hard is it to replace an AC plug.

EDIT:

- The laptop won't turn on. I've tried several different power
  adapters.
- I've done it with and without the battery.
- Is there a way to check electricity to help confirm?

Comment: What are some of the symptoms you are having?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be a little more specific. Do you know if the battery is charged? Are you positive the outlet you are plugged into has power? Are there any lights or sounds?

Comment: This might be of some help, although wrote for a tower it's still more or less the same method. http://superuser.com/questions/611689/computer-loop-restarts-on-windows-loading/611786#611786

Comment: a simple voltmeter would be useful for 1&2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it without the battery inserted, while plugged into the AC power.  Sometimes a poorly seated or malfunctioning battery can be the cause.  If it works, this doesnt mean your battery is bad.. Then try it with the battery installed to be certain.  Also, you can try holding down the power button while the battery is out and it is unplugged from the AC power, then connect to AC and try again if it doesnt work the first time.  This will discharge any stored charge from the PSU hopefully.  Also try the reverse, with battery installed and no AC power to rule out bad power brick.  If your battery has no charge, this will obviously not work though and if the power brick is broken you will be unable to charge that battery. If this doesnt work, leave the battery out and, if you have more than one stick of Ram, try removing a stick and then powering on to see if a bad stick of ram is causing a short.