# Samsung Series 9 in endless reboot loop

Tags: windows-8, boot

I have a Samsung Series 9 that I needed to do a system restore on. After restore everything looked good so I rebooted it and it went into this endless loop. It shows the Samsung logo, then goes into a Windows 8 "Preparing Automatic Repair" screen, then into a BSOD, then reboots. Over and over and over.

I have tried getting into the BIOS to see if I can boot it from a USB stick but it goes into the Windows screens immediately so it never reads the keyboard.

Any idea how I can fix this thing?

Answer (score 0):

I've had something similar happen to me with a tower once, problem was a dieing power supply.

Easiest way to check, disconnect the power supply, plug in another one and see if it works, normally no problem but since you're using a laptop not so easy to check.

So rule out the software first, take a linux distro such as ubuntu, burn it to disc or install it on a flash drive and try to run it live, if it crashes as well, it's not a software issue.

At this point you have the options of attempting to disassemble the laptop yourself and manually check each piece of hardware or take it to a local shop.

For relevant info, although relating to towers check this question out.

[Computer loop restarts on Windows loading](https://superuser.com/questions/611689/computer-loop-restarts-on-windows-loading/611786#611786)