# Computer broken, nothing on screen, replaced motherboard, checked PSU, what is wrong?

Tags: motherboard

so I have this computer, the person told me it froze so he turned it off by holding the power button, and then he couldn't turn it on again. There's nothing coming up on the monitor, the monitor is on stand by when you turn the pc on.

I took it with me and tried it on my monitor, my vga cable, still nothing on screen. I opened it up, cpu fan is spinning, and you can hear the HDD start up, but it doesn't do any loading, the loading light thing at the front doesn't flash.

It has on board graphics but I put in a dedicated video card in it, didn't fix the problem.

I got a power supply tester, tested the psu, it outputs the right voltages.

I bought and put in another motherboard, still doesn't fix the problem.

I tried to start it up with only 1 RAM stick, tried both of them individually, still doesn't fix the problem.

The HDD works, I have this sata to usb adapter, I can access all the files.

I'm running out of ideas, could it be a broken processor? The mobo doesn't beep or anything.

Edit: Removed all RAM, motherboard doesn't beep.

Edit2: For those wondering I gave up, didn't replace the CPU, the client decided to just buy a new PC since this one is quite shitty.

Comment: Beeps come from a small beeper that usually attaches to a couple of pins on the motherboard. No beeper, no beeps. Check motherboard manual to determine which pins (usually SPKR or similar). This beeper is a hangover from the ancient days when the only sound a PC could make was a beep, these days is rarely used except for BIOS diagnositics, so is sometimes not included.

Comment: Found a good picture of a beeper attached to a motherboard [here](http://www.computeronline.com.au/products.php?C_ID=5&S_ID=28&PROD=44387).

Comment: Thanks, there's definitely something on the motherboard that looks like a beeper. Its built into the mobo.

Comment: Ya.  Most motherboards have the beep module soldered onto them anymore.  As to the question, if it isn't making any beeps, I'd start to suspect the processor.  Without a working processor, I don't think it'll make any diagnostic noises.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Computer loop restarts on Windows loading](http://superuser.com/questions/611689/computer-loop-restarts-on-windows-loading)

Comment: Have you trired booting using a live cd/usb ?

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend you trying to change the CPU or just taking another to test... In my experience, this would be only the Motherboard or te CPU, as you say you recently changed the MB then i recommend you to change or just take another one of the same socket and test.

Try removing the RAM to see if the motherboard will beep..

HDD spinning doesnt mean nothing..

And when this happens, always try to use onboard video to reduce the errors risk.

Comment: Removed the RAM, mobo doesn't beep.

Comment: probrably is the Mobo or the CPU then. Try changing them with other computer to see.. First the CPU

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried taking the motherboard out of the case, and hooking it all up, it could be a short caused by a design, or misplaced motherboard riser.

Can also try:

- Try to use another equivalent processor.
- Clear the CMOS by using the jumper for `clear CMOS`.
- Replace the CMOS battery.